# Instagram style post heading stick to top of page and then get replaced by next one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Making a web app similar to instragrams layout and the post items have a full width image and then a div heading above each once.

e.g.

```
<div class="blogpost">
    <div class="blogtitle">
    </div>
    <div class="blogimage">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a simple list of the posts with the title above. On instragram, once the title hits the tops of the page (because of user scroll) that title div is fixed. Once the user scrolls more and the next title div meets the bottom of the current fixed once, the current one is pushed up and the new one fixed to the stop.

Any help on this?

Comment: @ManofSnow nice try... :|

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to create a site that uses parallax scrolling.  Here is a [link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/) to a helpful site.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable with a value of zero, and check (in JQuery) `$('.blogtitle').eq('variableWithZero')offset().scrollTop()` and if it's zero, change its position to **fixed,** and add one to the variable with zero.  Before that, `remove()` *(.blogTitle).eq('numberWithZero - 1)*

This will only help with scrolling up, but it should get you started ;)